# change the order of dropdown on its event change

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am adding a component to the dom based on the button click.

```
<button onClick={() => addQuestion("Template 1")}> Template 1 </button>
<button onClick={() => addQuestion("Template 2")}> Template 3 </button>
<button onClick={() => addQuestion("Template 3")}> Template 3 </button>
```

Also I have a select tag with the same value as button. If the user wish to change the type of, the option component will change.

```
<select id="q-type" onChange={(e)=>ChangeQType(e)}>
    <option value="Template 1">Template 1</option>
    <option value="Template 2">Template 2</option>
    <option value="Template 3">Template 3</option>
</select>
```

**What is working** : If I change the value in select tag the expected component renders.

**What is not working** : If I press a button , the expected components renders but the order of the dropdown is not changing. I need the rendered component value on top of the dropdown.

If I press Template 2 button I need in this order

```
<select id="q-type" onChange={(e)=>ChangeQType(e)}>
    <option value="Template 2">Template 2</option>
    <option value="Template 1">Template 1</option>
    <option value="Template 3">Template 3</option>
</select>
```

What i get :

```
<select id="q-type" onChange={(e)=>ChangeQType(e)}>
    <option value="Template 1">Template 1</option>
    <option value="Template 2">Template 2</option>
    <option value="Template 3">Template 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to first remove item from array and again place it in first. Here, I have place data on state hook. It would be easier to understand.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [templates, setTemplates] = useState(['Template 1', 'Template 2', 'Template 3']);
  const addQuestion = (item) => {
    let clone = [...templates];
    let objIndex = clone.indexOf(item);
    clone.splice(objIndex, 1);
    setTemplates([item, ...clone]);
  }
  const ChangeQType = () => {

  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => addQuestion("Template 1")}> Template 1 </button>
      <button onClick={() => addQuestion("Template 2")}> Template 2 </button>
      <button onClick={() => addQuestion("Template 3")}> Template 3 </button>
     
      <hr />
      <select id="q-type" onChange={(e) => ChangeQType(e)}>
        {templates.map((item) => <option value={item}>{item}</option>)}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```